# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) i

Tags: mysql, git, drupal, drupal-7, acquia

I am cloning a drupal site from github and I am using acquia dev desktop.

Whenever i first clone a site, the site is able to work just fine. However whenever i seem to do something with git - like fetch a new branch or add a remote, or something like that I start to get this error:

[![PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/global.ny.gov/docroot/includes/lock.inc).][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygv6U.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygv6U.png)

This was not happening until recently. Im not sure if this is a git problem, a local disk memory problem, or perhaps a settins.php problem that occurs when i checkout other branches? I have been workin on this issue for like 2 days now and none of the suggested solutions on drupal's forum seem to be working from me. Further than that - most answers on the drupal site are from like 5 years ago.

The problem first occurred when i cloned multiple Drupal sites on my machine.
I have a MAC. Any idea as to why this randomly happens?

127.0.0.1   mysite.dd

in /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

Does the Git pull (or similar) update a settings.php file?
Can you check the settings.php after the Git pull and confirm the DB settings are still correct?

Do you use [Drush](http://www.drush.org/en/master/)?

If not I suggest you install it. Then do a 'drush status' at the command line in your site docroot and see whether it connects to the DB.
You can also do 'drush sql-connect' to get the DB connect string Drupal is using.

Also I have seen this error occur after a migration and it was resolved by emptying the cache tables.
To do this use the SQL command:
'TRUNCATE cache'
And do the same for all tables beginning with 'cache_'.